# Angular 2 routing not working with ASP.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

i'm working in an ASP.NET Core Web Application, using Angular 2 and VS 2015 as IDE. This is totally new for me, so i've been following every tutorial to get this page work. When i finally put everything together i face a routing problem: The page stays in the loading... tag and never show the content in the ModuleViewComponent. Read a lot of stackoverflow questions but I could not fix it.

My **main.ts** file looks like this:

```
// main entry point
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

the **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { ModuleViewComponent } from './components/CommonComponents/moduleView.component/moduleView.component';

const myRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'home',
    component: ModuleViewComponent
},
{
    path: '/',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(myRoutes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ModuleViewComponent
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template:'<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

And the **index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<my-app>loading...</my-app>
```

How can i get this to work and show the component content? Any help is more than welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample application which explains step by step details to create angular (Angular v4) applications with Asp.net MVC framework. Below is the link. Hope this helps you. You have to update route config file in your project so that angular can receive requests.

http://hive.rinoy.in/angular4-and-asp-net-mvc-hybrid-application/

http://hive.rinoy.in/routing-in-angular-asp-net-mvc-application/

Comment: I'm going to try it and i'll let you know

Comment: provided links are dead.